# How does Spring apply proxy on a configuration bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

As we know, all the @Bean methods in a @Configuration class will be proxied, so that `foo()` will be invoked only once when it's a singleton.

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig{

@Bean
public Foo foo() {
    return new Foo();
}

@Bean
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public Bar bar() {
    return new Bar(foo()); // foo() will be invoked only once.
}

}
```

Is that proxy mechanism powered by Spring AOP? I doubt NOT, since Spring AOP is proxy-based(CGLIB) and it has [a self-invocation issue](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies), while `foo` doesn't have. It's based on AspectJ neither, because `SomeConfig` doesn't have an interface.

So how does Spring apply proxy on a configuration bean? What does this **get redirected** mean [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.21.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-basic-concepts)? Thanks!

> In common scenarios, @Bean methods are to be declared within @Configuration classes, ensuring that 'full' mode is always used and that cross-method references will therefore get redirected to the container’s lifecycle management. This will prevent the same @Bean method from accidentally being invoked through a regular Java call which helps to reduce subtle bugs that can be hard to track down when operating in 'lite' mode.

Comment: Yes it is proxy based, yes it is powerd by Spring. It is processed very early and processed through ASM, which is also used to proxy it with cglib. allowing all the things that a normal proxy cannot do.